# How to add/modify LDAP USer Federation at Keycloak startup

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I have set up Keycloak on Kubernetes using https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak helm chart.

I want to automatically add LDAP to it when deployed for the first time or modify it if the definition file changed.

I managed to set it up via REST API, but this has to be done manually after the server is already up and running and it doesn't work for modifications, because then a second entry is added and the first one is left untouched.

Any ideas about how to achieve it? Is there a way to put LDAP config file somewhere in the file system so it will be read by Keycloak? Or maybe is it achievable by CLI, but before the keycloak is running?

Comment: Did you find how to do it?

Comment: @Fieuxcédric I created a bash script and attached it to the pod via configmap. Then I created secret with LDAP configuration. All of this is here: https://github.com/maindev/main-dev-env/blob/master/specs/values/keycloak-init-ldap.yaml.gotmpl Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Ok thanks i did otherwise, i created my own keycloak docker image with realm inside import folder